# How to start/stop windows service from a remote machine through WCF service?

Tags: wcf, wcf-security, wcf-client

I have created a WCF service which is deployed on my local machine. This service exposes one method which start/stop a windows service on my local machine.

On the remote machine I have created a client that consumes the WCF service. When I try to invoke the method which start/stop service exposed from a WCF service , I get InvalidOperationException . I found that this is the Security issue.

Also when I do the same operation (start/stop windows service) on the local machine it works!!

The WCF service is hosted on IIS 7.0 which is using basichttpBinding. Also Anonnymous access is checked. I have also added `<identity Impersonate = true >` under the web section in the web config file but still no success.

Please help!!

Comment: 10 questions and only 2 accepted answers - it is good habit to accept answers. Otherwise people will not be motivated to answer your questions.

Answer (score 2):

You set impersonation for ASP.NET. Impersonation in WCF uses its own [infrastructure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730088.aspx). Moreover in WCF client has to allow service to impersonate his identity. Check this simple [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731090.aspx).